# Python TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

The following code is giving me error Python

`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable:`

Code:

```
hosts = 2
AppendMat = []
Mat = np.zeros((hosts,hosts))
Mat[1][0] = 5
for i in hosts:
    for j in hosts:
        if Mat[i][j]>0 and Timer[i][j]>=5:
            AppendMat.append(i)
```

How could I fix the error -

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable?
```

Secondly how can I append both the values of i and j if the if condition is true? Here I'm trying to append i only.

Comment: `for i in range(hosts): for j in range(hosts)`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for i in xrange(hosts):
```

Comment: range(hosts) if you're using Python 3.x is the same as xrange(hosts) in Python 2.x

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate over a range based on `hosts`, not `hosts` itself:

```
for i in range(hosts):      # Numbers 0 through hosts-1
    for j in range(hosts):  # Numbers 0 through hosts-1
```

You can append both numbers as a tuple:

```
 AppendMat.append((i,j))
```

or simply append them individually

```
AppendMat.extend([i,j])
```

depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

`hosts` is an `int`, so `for i in hosts` will not work, as the error explains. Perhaps you meant

```
for i in range(hosts):
```

The same goes for the second `for`-loop.

(See [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range); in Python 2.x use [`xrange()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange))

---

By the way this whole thing can be a single [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
AppendMat = [i for i in range(hosts) 
                   for j in range(hosts) 
                       if Mat[i][j]>0 and Timer[i][j]>=5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot iterate over integer (`hosts`):

```
>>> for i in 2:
...     print(i)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

You should use `range(n)` to iterate `n` times:

```
>>> for i in range(2):
...     print(i)
...
0
1
```

Answer (score 1):

probably you meant range(2) instead of `hosts`

Answer (score 1):

the `for` statement apply to the Python concept "iterable", like list, tuple, etc.. An int is not an iterable.

so you should use `range()` or `xrange()`, which receive an int and produce an iterable.

second, do you mean append a tuple: `append((i,j))` or a list: `append([i,j])` ? I'm not quite clear about the question.