# Python- TypeError object int is not iterable

Tags: python, typeerror

Here is my code, when I am running it I get error on line 19 (for loop):
TypeError: object 'int' is not iterable.

```
import fb 
from facepy import GraphAPI 


token=""# access token here.  
facebook=fb.graph.api(token)
graph1 = GraphAPI(token)
vid="" #page  id here
query=str(vid)+"/feed"
r=graph1.get(query)
count=0
nos=input("Enter number of posts: ")
for indid in nos:
      count=count+1
     facebook.publish(cat="feed",id=indid,message="Hi"+str(count))
  time.sleep(6)
  print("Wall post:"+str(count))

else :
   print("No posts made.")
```

Please tell me what's wrong.

Comment: Please do some research, this is an extremely basic error and simply googling your error message should lead you to many SO questions about the same problem; e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523563/python-typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887381/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-iterable-in-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595695/python-typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable et cetera.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the error says it all: you try to iterate over an `int` in the `for` loop of this code:

```
nos=input("Enter number of posts: ") # nos is an int here
for indid in nos: # and this is not how you iterate over an int
      count=count+1
     facebook.publish(cat="feed",id=indid,message="Hi"+str(count))
```

make a range instead:

```
for count in range(0, nos):
     facebook.publish(cat="feed",id=count,message="Hi"+str(count))
```

furthermore: I don't know what you try to do with `indid`. Maybe you also want to ask for the postid you want to change...

Comment: `range(nos)` works just as well