# Adding values to dictionary, int is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to either add a new value to a dictionary or increment the value (depending on whether the key is found or not) and I'm running in to an error message saying:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/james/Desktop/names.py", line 30, in 
>       scores(boys)   File "C:/Users/james/Desktop/names.py", line 14, in scores
>       totals.update(map(score,1)) TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

The line throwing the problem is:

```
totals.update(map(score,1))
```

and the full code is:

```
import csv
def scores(names):
    totals = {}
    values = {"a": 1, "b": 3, "c": 3, "d": 2, "e": 1, "f": 4, "g": 2, "h": 4, "i":1, "j": 8, "k": 5, "l": 1, "m": 3, "n": 1, "o": 1, "p": 3, "q": 10, "r": 1, "s": 1, "t": 1, "u": 1, "v":4, "w": 4, "x": 8, "y": 4, "z": 10}
    score = 0
    for name in names:
        for letter in name:
            letter = letter.lower()
            if (letter in values):
                score = score + int(values.get(letter))
        if (score in totals):
            totals.update(map(score,score.get(score)+1))
            #presumably this would throw an error
        else:
            totals.update(map(score,1))
            #this is the line throwing the error
        score = 0
    print (totals)    

boys = set()
girls = set()
with open ("names.txt") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        row = row[0].split(",")
        if (row[0]=="B"):
            boys.add(row[1])
        else:
            girls.add(row[1])
print (len(boys))
print (len(girls))
scores(boys)
scores(girls)
```

For context, I have a massive csv of Scottish children's names 1974-2016 stored as `names.txt` and I'm trying to get the frequency of the different Scrabble scores for them.  I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26669520/python-typeerror-object-int-is-not-iterable) and the answers linked from it but, as best I can tell, I'm not actually trying to iterate over `score`

Comment: `map(score,1)`: `1` is not an iterable, `map` expects an iterable.

Comment: So do it as a range?

Comment: That works, thank you.  Throw it up as an answer and I'll give you some reputation love

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this block cannot work because `map` takes an *iterable* as second argument (you don't need `map` at all here, `map` applies a function to all elements of an iterable)

```
    if (score in totals):
        totals.update(map(score,score.get(score)+1))
    else:
        totals.update(map(score,1))
```

Behind your totally bogus code (had to be said :)), you want to count how many times a given score is reached, so you need:

```
import collections
totals = collections.Counter()
```

then simply:

```
totals[score] += 1
```

Comment: And yeah, my code's awful.  I decided to use this as a way of learning some Python, I'm still at the "messing around with it" stage.  Absolutely no offence taken!

Comment: you'll have to be careful with python, because trying stuff at random sometimes has very suprising effects. So read the documentation / online help and look at examples/tutorials, it will be better :)

Comment: It is worth pointing that map has nothing to do with dict elements. map is used for execute function for every element in collection. [More info](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#map)